# Correct Response Code from ASP.NET Web API Delete operation when Delete fails because of other dependencies

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, http-response-codes

In my ASP.NET WEB API controller, I have exposed actions equivalent to the HTTP verbs :- Post, Put, Get and Delete, as follows:-

```
PostLocation
PutLocation
DeleteLocation
GetLocation
GetAllLocations
```

The Location objects are referred in another object called Devices which indicates the location in which the devices are installed.

Now when I invoke DeleteLocation action with a location ID, the Delete should be successful only when the location is not referred in any devices. If they are referred in any devices, the Delete action should send a response indicating that the location is referenced and cannot be deleted.

My question is :- What is the correct HttpResponse code that should be sent from the Delete action to indicate a failure due to such a reference and what should be given in the response body?

Comment: Any suggestions please? Has anyone worked with similar scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking at [HTTP 400 Bad Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1) or 409 Conflict. Your call on which best suits your situation.

As for the response body, whatever messages you return, be as verbose as possible. Errors should be the exception so allocate those extra bytes to help the developer as much as possible.

The JSON structure that we use, borrows from the advice given by the guys at apigee.

- Message - A friendly descriptive message that could be shown to an actual user
- developerMessage - More appropriate message for the developer to save them looking up doco
- code - Custom error code to expand on HTTP codes
- moreInfo - URL to documentation

Check the apigee [blog](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors) and ["Rest API tutorial"](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) for more details on errors and status codes.